# What is wrong with Steam version detection on my Mint 21?

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, upgrade, steam

```
$ apt-cache policy steam-launcher
steam-launcher:
  Installed: 1:1.0.0.74
  Candidate: 1:1.0.0.74
  Version table:
 *** 1:1.0.0.74 500
        500 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable/steam amd64 Packages
        500 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable/steam i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I just upgraded to Linux Mint 21 (based on Ubuntu 22) and saw that there is a newer version `steam-launcher_1.0.0.75_all.deb` (2022-Jul-12).[[link]](https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/pool/steam/s/steam/)

---

Here is my sources.list of steam.list:

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
```

Can I do anything to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ (bold emphasis mine):

> For Linux distributions
>
> Stable releases of the Steam launcher can be found in
> [archive/stable/](https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/archive/stable/).
>
> **New beta releases appear in [archive/beta/](https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/archive/beta/) first.** After testing,
> the beta is either promoted to [archive/stable/](https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/archive/stable/), or superseded by
> a new beta.
>
> The apt package pool in [pool/](https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/pool/) only contains the newest stable
> release and the newest beta. **Use the version-numbered releases in
> archive/stable/** or archive/beta/ if you need a stable URL (in Arch
> PKGBUILDs, Gentoo ebuilds, etc.) or **if you need to scan a directory
> listing to watch for new releases** (in debian/watch etc.).

So while the newest beta appears in the pool directory, it's not (yet) referenced by the *stable* repository list but only by *beta*. The pool directory should not be checked directly (when not using a repository), but [archive/stable/](https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/archive/stable/) should instead as documented.

So you can:

- wait version 1.0.0.75 will be deemed stable (and will then be referenced by the *stable* repository), unless it's superseded first by a newer beta,
- or only this time you can download it directly (over HTTPS, so even if not signed by the repository the risk might be minimal) and accept the risk of it being *beta* rather than *stable*,
- or switch to the beta repository which references it so it becomes available using usual *apt* tools like `apt-cache policy`:

  ```
  deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ beta steam
  ```